# Fastest HTML Downloader

Tags: c#, html, multithreading

I want the fastest method to download the source of HTML with given URL address
Is there any solution beyond normal C# solutions like (WebClient Download or HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse)
that speed up fetching HTML source code ??

Comment: Are you talking "fastest" as in fastest download speed or fastest as in ease of use?

Comment: @Matti, the last line of his question basically address this.  Fastest download speed.

Answer (score 1):

I normally just use this function when downloading and viewing html.

```
string getHtml(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            // make request for web page
            HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string myPageSource = string.Empty;
            myPageSource = myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
            myWebResponse.Close();
            return myPageSource;
        }
```

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/994.html